# Is there a way to create a regex function where i can ignore the forward slash and remove the first word after the forward slash?

Tags: regex

/saddlebrown-firm-leather-wallet
this is my string , i want 
/firm-leather-wallet
The regular expression i want to create should remove the first word of the string after the slash and return the string with the slash intact .
this is my code

```
<?php
function remove($string) {
    $string = str_replace('/^\/[a-zA-Z]+-/', '', $string);
    return $string;
}
?>
```

Comment: `$string = preg_replace('/^\/[a-zA-Z]+-/', '/', $string);`